# How do I use HTML tags in an email using PHP?

Tags: php, html, email, opencart

I just got my last question answered but now I'm stuck again.. I'm using OpenCart and I want to change the style of my email you'll get when you register on my OpenCart webshop. But when I use add this for example, it just shows it in the email as normal text:

```
$message .= '<img src="logo.png" />' "\n";
```

When I searched it on Google, on every site it says that I have to use this:

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

I pasted it on a few places in my code but it never worked, it was still showing the HTML Tags as text in the email.

I will paste my code (from OpenCart) here and can somebody tell me then where I have to paste that code or just another way to use HTML in email via PHP?

```
<?php
class ModelAccountCustomer extends Model {
    public function addCustomer($data) {
        if (isset($data['customer_group_id']) && is_array($this->config->get('config_customer_group_display')) && in_array($data['customer_group_id'], $this->config->get('config_customer_group_display'))) {
            $customer_group_id = $data['customer_group_id'];
        } else {
            $customer_group_id = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id');
        }

        $this->load->model('account/customer_group');

        $customer_group_info = $this->model_account_customer_group->getCustomerGroup($customer_group_id);

        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "customer SET store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "', firstname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['firstname']) . "', lastname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['lastname']) . "', email = '" . $this->db->escape($data['email']) . "', telephone = '" . $this->db->escape($data['telephone']) . "', fax = '" . $this->db->escape($data['fax']) . "', salt = '" . $this->db->escape($salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 9)) . "', password = '" . $this->db->escape(sha1($salt . sha1($salt . sha1($data['password'])))) . "', newsletter = '" . (isset($data['newsletter']) ? (int)$data['newsletter'] : 0) . "', customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "', ip = '" . $this->db->escape($this->request->server['REMOTE_ADDR']) . "', status = '1', approved = '" . (int)!$customer_group_info['approval'] . "', date_added = NOW()");

        $customer_id = $this->db->getLastId();

        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "address SET customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_id . "', firstname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['firstname']) . "', lastname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['lastname']) . "', company = '" . $this->db->escape($data['company']) . "', company_id = '" . $this->db->escape($data['company_id']) . "', tax_id = '" . $this->db->escape($data['tax_id']) . "', address_1 = '" . $this->db->escape($data['address_1']) . "', address_2 = '" . $this->db->escape($data['address_2']) . "', city = '" . $this->db->escape($data['city']) . "', postcode = '" . $this->db->escape($data['postcode']) . "', country_id = '" . (int)$data['country_id'] . "', zone_id = '" . (int)$data['zone_id'] . "'");

        $address_id = $this->db->getLastId();

        $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "customer SET address_id = '" . (int)$address_id . "' WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_id . "'");

        $this->language->load('mail/customer');
```

Here starts the part of the code what is going to be visible in the email itself.
<--From here-->

```
        **$subject = sprintf($this->language->get('text_subject'), $this->config->get('config_name'));

        $message = sprintf($this->language->get('text_welcome'), $this->config->get('config_name')) . "\n\n";

        if (!$customer_group_info['approval']) {
            $message .= $this->language->get('text_login') . "\n";
        } else {
            $message .= $this->language->get('text_approval') . "\n";
        }

        $message .= $this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL') . "\n\n";
        $message .= $this->language->get('text_services') . "\n\n";
        $message .= $this->language->get('text_thanks') . "\n";
        $message .= $this->config->get('config_name');**
```

<--Till here-->

```
        $mail = new Mail();
        $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
        $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
        $mail->hostname = $this->config->get('config_smtp_host');
        $mail->username = $this->config->get('config_smtp_username');
        $mail->password = $this->config->get('config_smtp_password');
        $mail->port = $this->config->get('config_smtp_port');
        $mail->timeout = $this->config->get('config_smtp_timeout');             
        $mail->setTo($data['email']);
        $mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
        $mail->setSender($this->config->get('config_name'));
        $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
        $mail->setText(html_entity_decode($message, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
        $mail->send();

        // Send to main admin email if new account email is enabled
        if ($this->config->get('config_account_mail')) {
            $message  = $this->language->get('text_signup') . "\n\n";
            $message .= $this->language->get('text_website') . ' ' . $this->config->get('config_name') . "\n";
            $message .= $this->language->get('text_firstname') . ' ' . $data['firstname'] . "\n";
            $message .= $this->language->get('text_lastname') . ' ' . $data['lastname'] . "\n";
            $message .= $this->language->get('text_customer_group') . ' ' . $customer_group_info['name'] . "\n";

            if ($data['company']) {
                $message .= $this->language->get('text_company') . ' '  . $data['company'] . "\n";
            }

            $message .= $this->language->get('text_email') . ' '  .  $data['email'] . "\n";
            $message .= $this->language->get('text_telephone') . ' ' . $data['telephone'] . "\n";

            $mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));
            $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($this->language->get('text_new_customer'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            $mail->setText(html_entity_decode($message, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            $mail->send();

            // Send to additional alert emails if new account email is enabled
            $emails = explode(',', $this->config->get('config_alert_emails'));

            foreach ($emails as $email) {
                if (strlen($email) > 0 && preg_match('/^[^\@]+@.*\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i', $email)) {
                    $mail->setTo($email);
                    $mail->send();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function editCustomer($data) {
        $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "customer SET firstname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['firstname']) . "', lastname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['lastname']) . "', email = '" . $this->db->escape($data['email']) . "', telephone = '" . $this->db->escape($data['telephone']) . "', fax = '" . $this->db->escape($data['fax']) . "' WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "'");
    }

    public function editPassword($email, $password) {
        $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "customer SET salt = '" . $this->db->escape($salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 9)) . "', password = '" . $this->db->escape(sha1($salt . sha1($salt . sha1($password)))) . "' WHERE LOWER(email) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($email)) . "'");
    }

    public function editNewsletter($newsletter) {
        $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "customer SET newsletter = '" . (int)$newsletter . "' WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "'");
    }

    public function getCustomer($customer_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_id . "'");

        return $query->row;
    }

    public function getCustomerByEmail($email) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer WHERE LOWER(email) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($email)) . "'");

        return $query->row;
    }

    public function getCustomerByToken($token) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer WHERE token = '" . $this->db->escape($token) . "' AND token != ''");

        $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "customer SET token = ''");

        return $query->row;
    }

    public function getCustomers($data = array()) {
        $sql = "SELECT *, CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS name, cg.name AS customer_group FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer c LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_group cg ON (c.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id) ";

        $implode = array();

        if (isset($data['filter_name']) && !is_null($data['filter_name'])) {
            $implode[] = "LCASE(CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname)) LIKE '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "%'";
        }

        if (isset($data['filter_email']) && !is_null($data['filter_email'])) {
            $implode[] = "LCASE(c.email) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_email'])) . "'";
        }

        if (isset($data['filter_customer_group_id']) && !is_null($data['filter_customer_group_id'])) {
            $implode[] = "cg.customer_group_id = '" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_customer_group_id']) . "'";
        }   

        if (isset($data['filter_status']) && !is_null($data['filter_status'])) {
            $implode[] = "c.status = '" . (int)$data['filter_status'] . "'";
        }   

        if (isset($data['filter_approved']) && !is_null($data['filter_approved'])) {
            $implode[] = "c.approved = '" . (int)$data['filter_approved'] . "'";
        }   

        if (isset($data['filter_ip']) && !is_null($data['filter_ip'])) {
            $implode[] = "c.customer_id IN (SELECT customer_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_ip WHERE ip = '" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_ip']) . "')";
        }   

        if (isset($data['filter_date_added']) && !is_null($data['filter_date_added'])) {
            $implode[] = "DATE(c.date_added) = DATE('" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_date_added']) . "')";
        }

        if ($implode) {
            $sql .= " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $implode);
        }

        $sort_data = array(
            'name',
            'c.email',
            'customer_group',
            'c.status',
            'c.ip',
            'c.date_added'
        );  

        if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $data['sort'];   
        } else {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY name";   
        }

        if (isset($data['order']) && ($data['order'] == 'DESC')) {
            $sql .= " DESC";
        } else {
            $sql .= " ASC";
        }

        if (isset($data['start']) || isset($data['limit'])) {
            if ($data['start'] < 0) {
                $data['start'] = 0;
            }           

            if ($data['limit'] < 1) {
                $data['limit'] = 20;
            }   

            $sql .= " LIMIT " . (int)$data['start'] . "," . (int)$data['limit'];
        }       

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        return $query->rows;    
    }

    public function getTotalCustomersByEmail($email) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer WHERE LOWER(email) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($email)) . "'");

        return $query->row['total'];
    }

    public function getIps($customer_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "customer_ip` WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_id . "'");

        return $query->rows;
    }   

    public function isBanIp($ip) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "customer_ban_ip` WHERE ip = '" . $this->db->escape($ip) . "'");

        return $query->num_rows;
    }   
}
?>
```

The one that reads this, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mail->setText(html_entity_decode($message, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

Your setting it as text.
Try setting has HTML.

```
$mail->setHTML($message);
```